# Input replace last characters to the left JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this an issue.

I have an input box which contains the placeholder value "**660000**". So, when the user start typing e.g. "**1**" then "**4**" then "**5**", the input value start changing like "**660001**" then "**660014**" then "**660145**".

If it possible, I need only the last 4 values to be able to change, if a fifth key is pressed, gets dismissed.

I don't know if a jQuery o JavaScript functions can accomplish this. Maybe you guys can give me an idea to start.

Thanks!

Comment: This is certainly possible with JavaScript, what code do you have so far?

Comment: Why couldn't you just have the 66 sit there statically and then the editable part is only 4 characters long?

Comment: basically I have no code for this beside the HTML. I can't have only the 66 because the value can be 66000X or 6600XX or 660XXX or 66XXXX, where X are numbers, and the customer needs to type Xs then Enter and go to next field

Comment: I agree with @NH. - Can you have the "66" be a static element adjacent and to the left of the input box. Then when just add 660000 to whatever they entered in the input box?

Comment: Sorry @jcarapia I dn follow you. If I have a 66, the when I press "1" I get an 661 not a 660001. How can I replace characters from right to left?

Comment: @DanielPontoriero The HTML would look something like this `66<input type="number" max="9999">` . Then in your js file/script , you would do 660000 (not 66) + whatever value they entered. This approach will keep it simple. If you absolutely need to have the 66 inside the input field and have the numbers appear left to right it'll take a lengthier approach, but should be doable- let me know.

Comment: I need to validate it with a datalist, which it gets the autocomplete. That is why I was looking from something to go replaceing it from right to left.

Comment: Start with something like this http://jsfiddle.net/pZLcg/605/ . The right-to-left implementation with leading zeros will take a bit more work - search around and take a crack at it. I might give it a shot later - if I have time.

Comment: Thanks for you help @jcarapia but I need the 66 to be typed inside the input. :-S

Comment: The example in fiddle above has the 66 inside the input...

Comment: but the number I get is XXXX and not 66XXXX on submit

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqemx218/1044/) for this.

But things gets complicated when back button or delete button is pressed.

```
var input = document.querySelector('#my-text-box');

var insertedValueArray = [];
var prevInputValue = ""

input.addEventListener('input', function()
{
    if ((insertedValueArray.length < 4) && (input.value != '') && !isNaN(input.value)) {
        insertedValueArray.push((input.value).replace(prevInputValue, ''));
        var zeroString = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 4 - insertedValueArray.length; i++) {
            zeroString += '0';
        }    

        input.value = "66" + zeroString + insertedValueArray.join('');
        prevInputValue = input.value;
    } else {
        input.value = prevInputValue;
    }

});
```

If I explained you the code I'm storing the newly added values to an array (**insertedValueArray**). then join it before setting it as the **input.value**.

To generate the zeros in the middle i'm using a loop and the insertedValue array. length.

Here I'm checking for three conditions. To check the number of input does not exceed 4 and to check whether input is not empty or not a number.

Hope the code make sense to you. I didn't consider the "BACKSPACE" and "DELETE" key strokes.

Hope this helps

Comment: Great! ... I'm gonna give it a try, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Is not what I call an elegant solution, but it works for me haha. I post it just in case anyone came across some similar issue.

Here is the JS

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.datalist', function(e){

  if(e.keyCode == 13){ //13 for Enter

   var dataListActual = $('#datalist-ordenPractica-'+$practicaContador);

    switch ( dataListActual.val().length ) {
    case 1:
        dataListActual.val('66000'+dataListActual.val());
        break;
    case 2:
        dataListActual.val('6600'+dataListActual.val());
        break;
    case 3:
        dataListActual.val('660'+dataListActual.val());
        break;
    case 4:
        dataListActual.val('66'+dataListActual.val());
        break;
    case 5:
        dataListActual.val('6'+dataListActual.val());
        break;
    case 6:
        dataListActual.val(dataListActual.val());
        break;
    }


  }
```

This is the HTML

```
<input class="datalist inputDatalist" autocomplete="off" id="datalist-ordenPractica-1" name="datalist-ordenPractica-1" value="" list="practicas_list" style="display: inline-block;">
```

Thank all you guys for your help!